# Getting Bootstrap Grails Error

Tags: grails, groovy

While everything was working fine, I added few static constraints in my domain and dropped the database and recreated it. After that I am creating ADMIN And USER roles in bootstrap along with a Demo USER and DEMO Admin but I am getting a error :

```
    | Error 2016-03-31 13:33:21,834 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: null
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>  111 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    327 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    320 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|    296 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|    334 | innerRun . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run                              in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                              in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Bootstrap Code :

```
    def init = { servletContext ->
            if (!Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER")) {
                Role role = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER')
                role.save(failOnError: true)
                    User user = new User(username: 'testUser', password: 'password1', enabled: true)

                    UserProfile profile1 = new UserProfile(fullName: "TEST", contactPhone: "8888888888", contactEmail: "test@test.com", displayName: "TEST", invoiceEmail: "test@gmail.com", invoiceDueDate: new Date(), defaultMap: MapType.GOOGLE)
                    user.profile = profile1
                    Device device1 = new Device(gpsDateTime: new Date(), vehicleId: "TEST", vehicleModel: "Hundai", imeiNumber: "000000000000000").save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

                    def test = new Account(notifyEmail: "test@test.com", allowNotify: true, name: 'TEST Car', device: device1).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    user.addToDevices(device1)
user.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
                    UserRole userRole = new UserRole(user: user, role: role)
                    userRole.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
                }
            }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Include your bootstrap code with your question. Otherwise it's difficult to give you an answer.

Comment: Also share your domain class as well.

Comment: Error occurs in BootStrap in line 111, show us this code.

Comment: The error is coming when I am using user.save()

Comment: The line where everything is smushed into one line?

Comment: The issues is that all the things(Device,User Profile and Account) are getting saved in DB but the User is not getting saved.

Comment: @tim_yates which one?

Comment: `user.addToDevices(device1)user.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)`

Comment: @tim_yates these two are different lines. It's a copying mistake here. user.save() is written in next line.

Comment: your error indicates  111 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1 line 111 you need to look through what you are doing there

Comment: @vahid the problem is solved..thanks.